# AJAX request within the datatables plugin doesnt work in every part of my code

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, url, datatable

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 5, jquery and the datatables plugin in a project. My goal is to use the serverside function of datatables in order to retrieve data of a database and then to display the dat in a datatable. This works fine in one part of my code. Here you can see the jquery code where I use the datatables plugin:

```
var problemTable = $('#ProblemTable').DataTable({
    processing: true,  // show message while querying fro data
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/OverView/LoadProblems"
    }
});
```

As you can see in the following picture, the request is successful and my datatables gets filled as it should in the website.

[image: Success]

The request URL looks like this:

[image: Success_Url]

So far is everything fine. But now comes the part, which is driving me crazy. In a different jquery script I try to call again the the datatables method for a new datatable. The code looks like this:

```
$('.DeleteEntity').click(
function () {
    try 
    {
        var deleteTable = $('#DeleteTable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverside: true,
            destroy: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "/Administration/ShowEntriesDelete"
            } 
        });
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

This Ajax call doesnt work anymore. As you can see the following picture, the action method in C# Code fails.

[image: Error]

In this case, the request URL looks like this.

[image: Error_Url]

So here is my question: Why do I get this behavior although I use the same function in my jquery code? Or is there something which I got totally wrong?

I think that I have tried everything by now, but I still don´t get it. Both datatables look exact the same in HTML, only id and column headers are different.

I also looked for similar questions, but I couldn't find anything. I would be very glad if someone could give me a hint for this.

Best regards!

**EDIT:**
@Calvin Ananda

I adapted your answer and added both DataTable functions to one script, just for testing purpose. Here is the hole script.

```
var troubleshootingIDs = [];
$(document).ready(
    function () {

    // if I call this method, everything works just fine, the c# code throws an error (which it should) but the ajax method is successfull
    var problemTable = $('#ProblemTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,  // show message while querying fro data
        serverSide: true,
        "ajax":  "/Administration/ShowEntriesDelete"
    }); 

    // if I call this method, the ajax method doesnt get called, because there is absolute no data provided in the url 
    var deleteTable = $('#DeleteTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverside: true,
        destroy: true,
        "ajax": "/Administration/ShowEntriesDelete",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Description" },
            { "data": "Connection" },
            { "data": "Action" }
        ]

    });


    var table = $('#reasonTable').DataTable({
        pageLength: 2,
        lengthChange: false,
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [3],
                className: "hide_me"
            }
        ]
    }
    );

    var agentButton = $('.agentButton');


    $('td').on('click', '#BadgeContainer', function () {
        var IDs = [];
        $('#DocList').empty();
        $('.DocLinkID').each(function (counter) {
            IDs[counter] = $(this).html();
        });
        console.log(IDs);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/OverView/GetDocuments",
            traditional: true,
            data: { IDs: IDs },
            content: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: listDocuments
        });
    });



    $('#reasonTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        $('#SolutionList').empty();
        troubleshootingIDs = [];

        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }

        var selectedReason = $('.ReasonGuid', this).text();


        $.ajax({
            url: '/OverView/ReasonJson',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { 'selectedReason': selectedReason },
            success: handleJsonForWizard
        }
        );

    }
    );

    $('.SolutionButton').on('click',
        function () {

            var indexToRemove = [];
            var dummyArray = [];

            for (var counter = 0; counter < troubleshootingIDs.length; counter++) {
                if ($('#q' + (+counter * 2)).hasClass('btn-active')) {
                    indexToRemove.push(counter);
                }

                dummyArray[counter] = troubleshootingIDs[counter];
            }


            for (var counter = indexToRemove.length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
                dummyArray.splice(indexToRemove[counter], 1);
            }

            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/OverView/GetSolutions',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { troubleshootingIDs: dummyArray },
                    success: function (json) {
                        $('#SolutionList').empty();

                        try {
                            for (var counter = 0; counter < Object.keys(json).length; counter++) {
                                $('#SolutionList').append('<li class="list-group-item">' + json[counter] + '</li>');
                            }
                        }

                        catch (err) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );

    $('#ProblemTable tbody').on('click', '.WizardButton',
        function () {
            var IdToGet = $(this).attr('id');

            var url = '/OverView/Wizard?SelectedID=';

            window.location.replace(url + IdToGet);

        }

    );

    // Carousel fuction overriding (doesn't work wiht jquery template)

    $('.carousel-control.left').click(
        function () {

            var parentId = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id');

            $(parentId).carousel('prev');
        }
    );

    $('.carousel-control.right').click(
        function () {

            var parentId = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id');

            $(parentId).carousel('next');
        }
    );


    // comment to define

    $('.row #BackToTable').click(
        function () {
            window.location.replace("/OverView");
        }

    );



    $('body').on('click', '.AgentButton',
        function () {


            var idNum = $(this).attr('id');

            var num = idNum.substring(1);

            $('#' + idNum).toggleClass('btn-active');

            if ((num % 2) == 0) {

                var numToCompare = +num + 1;
                var classToCompare = $('#q' + numToCompare).attr('class');

                if (classToCompare == 'btn AgentButton btn-active') {
                    $('#q' + numToCompare).toggleClass('btn-active');
                }
            }


            else {

                var numToCompare = +num - 1;
                var classToCompare = $('#q' + numToCompare).attr('class');

                if (classToCompare == 'btn AgentButton btn-active') {
                    $('#q' + numToCompare).toggleClass('btn-active');
                }
            }

        }
    );


    function handleJsonForWizard(json) {

        initializeCarousel(json.ImgLinks);
        initializeAgent(json.Troubleshootings, json.TroubleshootingIDs);
    }


    function initializeCarousel(imgLinks) {

        $('#ReasonVisualisation > ol').empty();
        $('#ReasonVisualisation > .carousel-inner').empty();
        for (var counter = 0; counter < Object.keys(imgLinks).length; counter++) {
            $('#ReasonVisualisation > ol').append('<li data-target="#ReasonVisualisation" data-slide-to="' + counter + '"></li>');
            $('#ReasonVisualisation > .carousel-inner').append('<div class="item"><img src="' + imgLinks[counter] + '"/> </div>');
        }

        $('#ReasonVisualisation > ol >li:first').addClass('active');
        $('#ReasonVisualisation > .carousel-inner>div:first').addClass('active');

        var list = $('#ReasonVisualisation > ol').html();

        var inner = $('#ReasonVisualisation > .carousel-inner').html();


    }

    function initializeAgent(troubleshootings, ids) {
        $('#Agent').empty();
        for (var counter = 0; counter < Object.keys(troubleshootings).length; counter++) {
            $('#Agent').append('<div>' + troubleshootings[counter] + ' </div>');
            $('#Agent').append('<div class="btn AgentButton" id="q' + (counter * 2) + '">Yes</div>');
            $('#Agent').append('<div class="btn AgentButton" id="q' + ((counter * 2) + 1) + '">No</div>');
            agentButton = $('.AgentButton');
            troubleshootingIDs[counter] = ids[counter];
        }
    }


    function listDocuments(json) {
        //Array.isArray(json);
        if (json.length > 1) {
            for (var counter = 0; counter < json.length; counter++) {
                $('#DocList').append('<li> <a href=\"' + json[counter] + '\" > Link </a></li>');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

);

The most interesting part are the first to methods within the script. In my provided code within the code I described my issue. I simply don´t why ajax reacts so different...

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in my project, and it works.

But I dont know if it works to answer your problem.

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4httest8/)

Change to `"ajax": "/OverView/LoadProblems"`

```
var problemTable = $("#ProblemTable").DataTable({
    processing: true,  // show message while querying fro data
    serverSide: true,
    "ajax": "/OverView/LoadProblems"
});
```

=========================================================================

```
$(".DeleteEntity").click(
function () {
    try 
    {
        var deleteTable = $("#DeleteTable").DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverside: true,
            destroy: true,
            "ajax": "/Administration/ShowEntriesDelete"
        });
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but your provided modification didn´t work in my solution.

Comment: can you add $(document).ready(function() {}); to your script?

Comment: I´ve edited my post, yo can see the script there. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Are you sure about 'data' calling in 'columns' section? I think you're wrong in this section. That's not to make a name on your table, but calling the name on json.

Comment: I just added it, to test something. When I remove the columns, i still have th same Problem. In the function $("#DeleteTable").DataTable(..) the C# ActionResult Method gets called with this url: http://localhost:50827/Administration/ShowEntriesDelete?_=1510319036206

Comment: But in the method $("#ProblemTable").DataTable(...) there is actualy a lot of content in the url. Like this: Administration/ShowEntriesDelete?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns(... and more)

Comment: Yes. that's the main problem with data calling.

Comment: Your url can not be seen because it is in your localhost